# How can I simulate a beating heart?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios7

I am making a game and I want the heart to look like it is beating. My approach is to have two images of a heart. One is bigger then the other. I have one as a UIButton (because to start the game I want to click the heart to do so), and the other bigger version of the heart is as UIImageView. So far I have it so the heart changes size every second, but I want it to be more realistic. For example, every second, it will change to the big heart and back (but not instantly so it is clearly visible). How can I do this? Here is my code:

**PlayViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PlayViewController : UIViewController
{    
    IBOutlet UIButton *heartButton;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *heartBig;
    NSTimer *heartBeat;
}

@end
```

**PlayViewController.m**

```
#import "PlayViewController.h"

@interface PlayViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    heartBig.hidden = YES;

    heartBeat = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(beatHeart) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)beatHeart
{
    if(heartBig.hidden == true)
        heartBig.hidden = false;

    else
        heartBig.hidden = true;
}

@end
```

Comment: A heart does not simply get larger and smaller, but one part beats then the other.  Eg, try 3 images -- one "normal", one with the left side larger, one with the right side larger.

Comment: @HotLicks - You are assuming he is referring to a mammalian heart :-)

Comment: Even if it's a cartoon heart-shaped heart, the multi-phase animation will seem more life-like.

Comment: To avoid namespace collision with Class Names it's best to prefix your class name with initials. For example if your name is John Smith your class name could be `JSPlayViewController`. Just a suggestion to avoid namespace collisions but it's up to you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this pulse animation:

[image]

> ```
> CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
> theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
> theAnimation.duration=0.7;
> theAnimation.repeatCount=HUGE_VALF;
> theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
> theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
> theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7];
> theAnimation.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
> [self.heart.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
> ```

Comment: It's like a heart of this page. Thank you!

Comment: How can I animate as breaking heart?

Answer (score 8):

[image: Animation]

```
/**
 Heart beating animation
 */
func addHeartBeatAnimation () {
    let beatLong: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    beatLong.fromValue = NSValue(CGSize: CGSizeMake(1, 1))
    beatLong.toValue = NSValue(CGSize: CGSizeMake(0.7, 0.7))
    beatLong.autoreverses = true
    beatLong.duration = 0.5
    beatLong.beginTime = 0.0

    let beatShort: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    beatShort.fromValue = NSValue(CGSize: CGSizeMake(1, 1))
    beatShort.toValue = NSValue(CGSize: CGSizeMake(0.5, 0.5))
    beatShort.autoreverses = true
    beatShort.duration = 0.7
    beatShort.beginTime = beatLong.duration
    beatLong.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn )

    let heartBeatAnim: CAAnimationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    heartBeatAnim.animations = [beatLong, beatShort]
    heartBeatAnim.duration = beatShort.beginTime + beatShort.duration
    heartBeatAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    heartBeatAnim.removedOnCompletion = false
    heartBeatAnim.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
    self.layer.addAnimation(heartBeatAnim, forKey: nil)
}
```

Based on BCBlanka's answer, little more realistic animation

Comment: How can I animate as breaking heart?

Comment: Nice animation! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

> So far I have it so the heart changes size every second, but I want it to be more realistic.

The obvious suggestion is to use a sequence of images, to give you a "smooth" animation.

Comment: How can I animate as breaking heart?

Comment: Same answer as above.

Comment: but I am using bazier path to dispaly heart .

Comment: Well that's not what my answer recommends.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 code:

```
    let pulse = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    pulse.duration = 0.4
    pulse.fromValue = 1.0
    pulse.toValue = 1.12
    pulse.autoreverses = true
    pulse.repeatCount = .infinity
    pulse.initialVelocity = 0.5
    pulse.damping = 0.8
    button.layer.add(pulse, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: this anim looks weird... it is not smooth when looping

Answer (score 0):

BCBlanka used Core Animation, if anyone wants to use Facebooks POPAnimation library this would be the implementation:

```
POPBasicAnimation *beatingHeartAnim = [POPBasicAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPViewScaleXY];
beatingHeartAnim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
beatingHeartAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
beatingHeartAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(0.7, 0.7)];
beatingHeartAnim.autoreverses = YES;
beatingHeartAnim.duration = 1.0;
beatingHeartAnim.repeatCount = 120;
[heart  pop_addAnimation:beatingHeartAnim forKey:@"beatingHeartAnim"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example with Facebook's POP, with a more "natural" pulse.

```
POPBasicAnimation *pulseAnimation = [POPBasicAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPViewScaleXY];
pulseAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
pulseAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
pulseAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(1.1, 1.1)];

pulseAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
pulseAnimation.duration = 1.0;
pulseAnimation.repeatForever = YES;
[self pop_addAnimation:pulseAnimation forKey:@"pulseAnimation"];
```